# using print with a comma in python 3

Tags: python

Using python 3 `print()`, does not list the repeated data one after the other on the same line?

Let's say you want a message to display on the same line and repeatedly.

example.

```
my_message = 'Hello'
for i in range(100) :
    print(my_message),
```

it IS CURRENTLY printing one below the other.(not what I want)

```
hello 
hello
hello.....
```

but I read in the python book that adding a comma , after print(), should create the desired effect and would make it display side by side

```
hello hello hello hello..(x100)
```

why doesn't it do that in Python 3? How do you fix it?

Comment: the comma thing is only in python 2, because there `print` is a statement like `if`, `for` etc and to indicate that you don't want a new line you need to indicate it with a comma in the end. In python 3, alongside many other thing, they change it to a build-in function that give you more flexibility in how to handle it, take a look at `help(print)` for details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does not work in Python 3 because in Python 3, `print` is a function.  To get the desired affect, use:

```
myMessage = "Hello"
for i in range(100):
    print(myMessage, end=" ")
```

or more concisely:

```
print(" ".join("Hello" for _ in range(100)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `print()` is a function in Python 3, you can pass multiple arguments to it using the `*`-operator.

You can do this with a tuple:

```
print(*('Hello' for x in range(100)))
```

Or with a list (created by a list comprehension):

```
print(*['Hello' for x in range(100)])
```

Another way would be to use `join()`:

```
print(' '.join('Hello' for x in range(100)))
```

You can also use the `end` keyword:

```
for x in range(100):
    print('Hello', end=' ')
```

In **Python 2.x** this was possible:

```
for x in xrange(100):
    print 'Hello',
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, simply

```
print(*('Hello' for _ in range(5)))
```

There is no need to create a list or to use `join`.

To have something other than one space between each "Hello", pass the `sep` argument (note it's keyword-only):

```
print(*('Hello' for _ in range(5)), sep=', ')
```

gives you

```
Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello
```